# How to remove BLANK spaces while converting HTML to TEXT using libxml2 HTMLParser

Tags: libxml2

How to condense multiple white spaces to single/remove all white spaces here? see the following source code and example input.

```
void walkTree(xmlNode * a_node) {
          xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;
          for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) {
            if (cur_node->type == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
              printf("%s", cur_node->content);
            }
            walkTree(cur_node->children);
          }
        }

void main () {
    htmlParserCtxtPtr parser = htmlCreatePushParserCtxt(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
    htmlCtxtUseOptions(parser, HTML_PARSE_NOBLANKS | HTML_PARSE_NOERROR | HTML_PARSE_NOWARNING | HTML_PARSE_NONET);
    len = ReadFile(data);
    htmlParseChunk(parser, data, len, 0);
    walkTree(xmlDocGetRootElement(parser->myDoc));
}



input: "<table><tbody><tr><td><b>Updated by:</b>                     </td><td >Test</td></tr></tbody></table><br/>"


output: "Updated by:                 Test"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function:

```
str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isspace), str.end());
```